# Install blender on CAELinux

Tags: linux

i am a newbie at the linux environment, please how can i install blender on Linux? what are the commands i type on the terminal window? i just download it from the website. thank you
[image]

Comment: If you download the compressed tarball, all you need to do is extract it and run the blender executable contained within.

Comment: I fail to see what the reason is for including thing image?

Answer (score 1):

CAELinux is based on Debian, right? If so, these are the commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:thomas-schiex/blender

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install blender

sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`
```

[Heres a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehq0Zkit99E) in case you don't understand some of these.

Source: I've been a Blender guru since 2009. Best program ever created if you ask me!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alan, well yes i do have questions :), i am using the molecular add-on with an imported part from SolidWorks, the thing is that when i switch to the animation section, first thing it moves to the second layer which is empty, the second when i animate it, it doesn't show the particles "molecular add-on" ones and how to save the animation into AVI file with colors cause right now everything is gray, That's all i have lol

Comment: Not sure about the molecular add on, never used it. Mostly only used the game engine. But from what I can tell, you might not be in 'textured mode' on the material setting thing. I'm on a work computer now, so I dont have Blender installed and cant screenshot what I mean.

Comment: lol i google it and found it, now i see the colors, thanks , and what about the animation section, how can i just save the animation into AVI, this one i googled it found that i must use the output but where? and please please i want when i do the animation the camera will be far and then gets closer to the particles. i added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: @Hamza.w please keep the comments section to one topic and not add new questions here. Ask a new question if you like, comments can't be searched but questions can!

Comment: i will :) just add me some points :p
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32567/how-to-control-the-animation-section-to-make-avi-file

Comment: @Hamza.w I'm sure you will gain plenty of points once you start to appreciate how this site works. It will be slow at first, but worth the perseverance.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to make a *symbolic link* to the portable binary from a downloaded archive

```
ln -s /home/your_archive/blender /usr/bin/b3d
```

This lets me start blender using `b3d` from command line.